# PyQt:How do I display a image properly?

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to display an image in pyqt so,i used a label and the pixmap option,and the scaledContents but the image is distorted.Should I use another widget or do something else? Thanks.

This is the code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8('image.jpg')))
self.label.setScaledContents(True)
```

I use QtDesigner.

I tried this:            `self.label.pixmap().scaled(QtCore.QSize(self.label.size()), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)`

but the images don't get resized to fit the label.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `scaled(const QSize, Qt::AspectRatioMode, Qt::TransformationMode)` method of the pixmap, it has an option `Qt::KeepAspectRatio` that does not deform the image. The default is to ignore the aspect ratio

Also, note that the `scaled` method returns the scaled `pixmap`, so it must be used this way:

```
myPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8('image.jpg'))
myScaledPixmap = myPixmap.scaled(self.label.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
self.label.setPixmap(myScaledPixmap)
```

Comment: self.label.pixmap().scaled(QSize(self.label.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation), Eventually you can choose a different size

Comment: I if i use the above after the :self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8('image.jpg')))
 it gives an error,of invalid syntax.

Comment: Oh, yes, I forget a bracket. Try this: self.label.pixmap().scaled(QSize(self.label.size()), Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)

Comment: There is a parenthesis missing.

Comment: Thanks for the correction,but now it gives: global name 'QSize' is not defined.

Comment: Depending on how you import the PyQt4 modules, it can be QtCore.QSize(...)

Answer (score 0):

*yourPixmapLabel.setScaledContents(True)* scales the pixmap to fill the free space and must be enough. otherwise let us see some code ex