# PyQt4: Scale image but keep dimensions

Tags: pyqt4, scale, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to scale down an image so it will fit to my QGraphicsView, but keep it's original width and height, so when a mouse press event occours, I will get the correct coordinates in that image.
Is that possible?

btw, in cv2, I can scale the width and height of the "imshow" window, and it will keep the right coordinates. I would hate to think that it is a hard task to do in Qt.

Thank you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt:How do I display a image properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687723/pyqthow-do-i-display-a-image-properly)

Comment: @ekhumoro I can't use label, because I need to use QPainter on that image...

Comment: You can use the scaled pixmap in any way you like: the label is irrelevant. (And here's an alternative dup that uses `QImage`: [How do I resize an image and maintain its proportions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19715232/984421))

Comment: Let's say I have an image in dimensions 5120x3072.
If I scale it down to 1024x614 and click on the bottom right corner of the image, the pos() method will return 1023, 613.. So the dimensions have changed...
btw, I don't care about the AspectRatio.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm kinda new with Qt

Comment: Never mind. I found my mistake. thank you